# Start process as another user using WindowsIdentity

Tags: c#, windows, web-services, owin, impersonation

I have service running in self hosting application. When request comes, I want to start a process as a user, from which the request had come from. In the example below, first message box shows User1 name, second User2, but the notepad runs as User1. how can I force it to start as User2?

```
MessageBox.Show(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);
using (((WindowsIdentity)RequestContext.Principal.Identity).Impersonate())
            {
                MessageBox.Show(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);
                Process.Start("Notepad.exe");
            }
```

Comment: Impersonation is ignored when starting a new process.  Perhaps the code at the start of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38274533/886887) would help?

Comment: yes, I plan to try to use [this method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682429(v=vs.85).aspx) to overcome my problem, but I wonder whether there is better way to do that, without Win API

Comment: ProcessStartInfo requires username and password. I don't have them, all I have is token

Comment: OK, I understand now.  Someone else may know for sure whether there's a way to do this in .NET without P/Invoking the Win32 API.

Comment: I don't think you can do it without P/Invoke, but the good news is that this answer suggest a complete code reference: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38490877/397604