# Impersonate user in Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows, c#-4.0, windows-services, impersonation

I am trying to impersonate a domain user in a windows service with the service logged in as the Local System Account.

So far, I am only able to get this to work by logging the service and set the process using the user credentials, like the following.

```
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.FileName = CommandDetails.Command;
        startInfo.WorkingDirectory = Settings.RoboCopyWorkingDirectory;
        startInfo.Arguments = commandLine;

        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

        // Credentials
        startInfo.Domain = ImperDomain;
        startInfo.UserName = ImperUsername;
        startInfo.Password = ImperPasswordSecure;

        process = Process.Start(startInfo);
```

My goal is to not have the service log in a domain user but rather as local system since the domain accounts passwords get reset.

When I use the local system, I get **Access is denied**

Any ideas how how to accomplish this?

StackTace

```
Access is denied

   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at Ace.WindowsService.ProcessCmd.ProcessCommand.StartProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo) in
```

I have tried wrapping the code in the Impersonate code listed below with no success.

**Impersonate Code**

```
public class Impersonation2 : IDisposable
{
    private WindowsImpersonationContext _impersonatedUserContext;

    // Declare signatures for Win32 LogonUser and CloseHandle APIs
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool LogonUser(
      string principal,
      string authority,
      string password,
      LogonSessionType logonType,
      LogonProvider logonProvider,
      out IntPtr token);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    static extern int DuplicateToken(IntPtr hToken,
        int impersonationLevel,
        ref IntPtr hNewToken);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool RevertToSelf();

    // ReSharper disable UnusedMember.Local
    enum LogonSessionType : uint
    {
        Interactive = 2,
        Network,
        Batch,
        Service,
        NetworkCleartext = 8,
        NewCredentials
    }
    // ReSharper disable InconsistentNaming
    enum LogonProvider : uint
    {
        Default = 0, // default for platform (use this!)
        WinNT35,     // sends smoke signals to authority
        WinNT40,     // uses NTLM
        WinNT50      // negotiates Kerb or NTLM
    }
    // ReSharper restore InconsistentNaming
    // ReSharper restore UnusedMember.Local

    /// <summary>
    /// Class to allow running a segment of code under a given user login context
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="user">domain\user</param>
    /// <param name="password">user's domain password</param>
    public Impersonation2(string domain, string username, string password)
    {
        var token = ValidateParametersAndGetFirstLoginToken(username, domain, password);

        var duplicateToken = IntPtr.Zero;
        try
        {
            if (DuplicateToken(token, 2, ref duplicateToken) == 0)
            {
                throw new Exception("DuplicateToken call to reset permissions for this token failed");
            }

            var identityForLoggedOnUser = new WindowsIdentity(duplicateToken);
            _impersonatedUserContext = identityForLoggedOnUser.Impersonate();
            if (_impersonatedUserContext == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("WindowsIdentity.Impersonate() failed");
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (token != IntPtr.Zero)
                CloseHandle(token);
            if (duplicateToken != IntPtr.Zero)
                CloseHandle(duplicateToken);
        }
    }

    private static IntPtr ValidateParametersAndGetFirstLoginToken(string domain, string username, string password)
    {


        if (!RevertToSelf())
        {
            throw new Exception("RevertToSelf call to remove any prior impersonations failed");
            ErrorLogger.LogEvent("RevertToSelf call to remove any prior impersonations failed", System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Error, "");

        }

        IntPtr token;

        var result = LogonUser(domain, username,
                               password,
                               LogonSessionType.Interactive,
                               LogonProvider.Default,
                               out token);
        if (!result)
        {
            var errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            ErrorLogger.LogEvent(string.Format("Could not impersonate the elevated user.  LogonUser: {2}\\{1} returned error code: {0}.", errorCode, username, domain), System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Error, "");
            throw new Exception("Logon for user " + username + " failed.");
        }
        return token;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Stop impersonation and revert to the process identity
        if (_impersonatedUserContext != null)
        {
            _impersonatedUserContext.Undo();
            _impersonatedUserContext = null;
        }
    }
```

**Update**

This works fine if I am just running if I am just executing it. But when it is running as a service, it will not work

**Update 2**

I am not getting the access denied from the Process.Start when I change the impersonating login to LogonSessionType.NewCredentials and remove the crednetials from the process.  But I now see an error when running the robocopy command. When I do have the credentials on the process it does not produce a log file from the robocopy command

**Error**

```
2016/07/16 09:19:12 ERROR 5 (0x00000005) 
Accessing Source Directory \\[server]\[path]\
Access is denied.
```

**Change**

```
var result = LogonUser(domain, username,
   password,
   LogonSessionType.NewCredentials,
   LogonProvider.Default,
   out token);
```

Update 3

The copy and move functions are working.  But creating sub process is not.    I have been playing with CreateProcessAsUser as Hary Johnston has suggested.

Comment: Are you saying that your service is running as `Local System`, and your service is starting another process using a domain user's account?

Comment: If so, this question is possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/559719/windows-impersonation-from-c-sharp

Comment: What line of code throws the "access denied" error?

Comment: process = Process.Start(startInfo);

Comment: @wablab,  You may be right.  But that question was looking to impersonate without the username and password.  Also, the new process seems to cause some issues.  based on Franci Penov answer, I am missing the OpenProcessToken,

Comment: Hold on, are you trying to impersonate the domain user, or are you trying to launch a process as the domain user?  Those are two different things.

Comment: @Harry Johnston. The ultimate goal is to have the local system run the service and for anything that needs to impersonate.  Ie copy files, start a process etc

Comment: Launching a child process (with different credentials) is complicated from a service.  It's also a very inefficient way to do most tasks.  There are a few things you can't do with impersonation, but not many, so unless you have a specific reason why you need a child process I strongly recommend you just use impersonation.

Comment: If you do want to launch a child process, Microsoft have sample code on MSDN, see [Starting an Interactive Client Process in C++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379608(v=vs.85).aspx).  [My answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20462713/886887) discusses this, and also provides sample code to demonstrate the user of Microsoft's sample code in a service.  You'd need to port Microsoft's code to C#, unless you can find equivalent third-party code somewhere.

Comment: ... oh, and you should probably put the child process into a job, too, configured so that it dies when the parent dies.  Otherwise the service can be stopped but the child process is still running, causing confusion and possibly breaking things if the service is then restarted.

Comment: Addendum: apparently, if you use CreateProcessAsUser, you don't actually need to mess about with window station permissions.  I haven't tested this, but assuming it is true it should make things easier.

Comment: @HarryJohnston  Thanks. I have been looking in that direction but I havent gotten it to work

Comment: AFAIK, there is no way to impersonate a user without having their login credentials. Most places setup an account that has the correct permissions and no password expiration for running services that require it.

Comment: I wasn't asking that.  I do have credentials.

Comment: @H20rider, I strongly recommend you to read [Launching an interactive process from Windows Service in Windows Vista and later](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/winsdk/2009/07/14/launching-an-interactive-process-from-windows-service-in-windows-vista-and-later/). This article covers many problems.

Comment: @H20rider, could you refresh you code? What you're trying to do now?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I was able to get it to work.

For normal impersonating, I used the following code

```
public class Impersonation : IDisposable
{
    private WindowsImpersonationContext _impersonatedUserContext;

    #region FUNCTIONS (P/INVOKE)

    // Declare signatures for Win32 LogonUser and CloseHandle APIs
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool LogonUser(
      string principal,
      string authority,
      string password,
      LogonSessionType logonType,
      LogonProvider logonProvider,
      out IntPtr token);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    static extern int DuplicateToken(IntPtr hToken,
        int impersonationLevel,
        ref IntPtr hNewToken);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool RevertToSelf();

    #endregion

    #region ENUMS

    enum LogonSessionType : uint
    {
        Interactive = 2,
        Network,
        Batch,
        Service,
        NetworkCleartext = 8,
        NewCredentials
    }

    enum LogonProvider : uint
    {
        Default = 0, // default for platform (use this!)
        WinNT35,     // sends smoke signals to authority
        WinNT40,     // uses NTLM
        WinNT50      // negotiates Kerb or NTLM
    }

    #endregion


    /// <summary>
    /// Class to allow running a segment of code under a given user login context
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="user">domain\user</param>
    /// <param name="password">user's domain password</param>
    public Impersonation(string domain, string username, string password)
    {
        var token = ValidateParametersAndGetFirstLoginToken(username, domain, password);

        var duplicateToken = IntPtr.Zero;
        try
        {
            if (DuplicateToken(token, 2, ref duplicateToken) == 0)
            {


                throw new InvalidOperationException("DuplicateToken call to reset permissions for this token failed");
            }

            var identityForLoggedOnUser = new WindowsIdentity(duplicateToken);
            _impersonatedUserContext = identityForLoggedOnUser.Impersonate();
            if (_impersonatedUserContext == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("WindowsIdentity.Impersonate() failed");
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (token != IntPtr.Zero)
                CloseHandle(token);
            if (duplicateToken != IntPtr.Zero)
                CloseHandle(duplicateToken);
        }
    }

    private static IntPtr ValidateParametersAndGetFirstLoginToken(string domain, string username, string password)
    {


        if (!RevertToSelf())
        {
            ErrorLogger.LogEvent("RevertToSelf call to remove any prior impersonations failed", System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Error, "");

            throw new InvalidOperationException("RevertToSelf call to remove any prior impersonations failed");

        }

        IntPtr token;

        var result = LogonUser(domain, username,
                               password,
                               LogonSessionType.NewCredentials,
                               LogonProvider.Default,
                               out token);
        if (!result)
        {
            var errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            ErrorLogger.LogEvent(string.Format("Could not impersonate the elevated user.  LogonUser: {2}\\{1} returned error code: {0}.", errorCode, username, domain), System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Error, "");
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Logon for user " + username + " failed.");
        }
        return token;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Stop impersonation and revert to the process identity
        if (_impersonatedUserContext != null)
        {
            _impersonatedUserContext.Undo();
            _impersonatedUserContext = null;
        }
    }
}
```

To run it I do the following:

```
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(logfile);
            using (var imp = new Impersonation(Settings.ImpersonateUser.AccountDomain, Settings.ImpersonateUser.AccountName, Settings.ImpersonateUser.AccountPassword))
            {
                if (File.Exists(filename))
                    File.Delete(filename);
                fi.MoveTo(filename);
            }
```

For running console commands, I used the following code.

```
public class CreateProcess
{

    #region Constants

    const UInt32 INFINITE = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    const UInt32 WAIT_FAILED = 0xFFFFFFFF;

    #endregion


    #region ENUMS

    [Flags]
    public enum LogonType
    {
        LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2,
        LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK = 3,
        LOGON32_LOGON_BATCH = 4,
        LOGON32_LOGON_SERVICE = 5,
        LOGON32_LOGON_UNLOCK = 7,
        LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK_CLEARTEXT = 8,
        LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS = 9
    }


    [Flags]
    public enum LogonProvider
    {
        LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0,
        LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT35,
        LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT40,
        LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT50
    }

    #endregion


    #region Structs

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct STARTUPINFO
    {
        public Int32 cb;
        public String lpReserved;
        public String lpDesktop;
        public String lpTitle;
        public Int32 dwX;
        public Int32 dwY;
        public Int32 dwXSize;
        public Int32 dwYSize;
        public Int32 dwXCountChars;
        public Int32 dwYCountChars;
        public Int32 dwFillAttribute;
        public Int32 dwFlags;
        public Int16 wShowWindow;
        public Int16 cbReserved2;
        public IntPtr lpReserved2;
        public IntPtr hStdInput;
        public IntPtr hStdOutput;
        public IntPtr hStdError;
    }


    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct PROCESS_INFORMATION
    {
        public IntPtr hProcess;
        public IntPtr hThread;
        public Int32 dwProcessId;
        public Int32 dwThreadId;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
    {
        public int nLength;
        public unsafe byte* lpSecurityDescriptor;
        public int bInheritHandle;
    }

    public enum TOKEN_TYPE
    {
        TokenPrimary = 1,
        TokenImpersonation
    }

    public enum SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL
    {
        SecurityAnonymous,
        SecurityIdentification,
        SecurityImpersonation,
        SecurityDelegation
    }

    #endregion


    #region FUNCTIONS (P/INVOKE)

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool RevertToSelf();

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    static extern int DuplicateToken(IntPtr hToken,
        int impersonationLevel,
        ref IntPtr hNewToken);


    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern Boolean LogonUser
    (
        String UserName,
        String Domain,
        String Password,
        LogonType dwLogonType,
        LogonProvider dwLogonProvider,
        out IntPtr phToken
    );


    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern Boolean CreateProcessAsUser
    (
        IntPtr hToken,
        String lpApplicationName,
        String lpCommandLine,
        IntPtr lpProcessAttributes,
        IntPtr lpThreadAttributes,
        Boolean bInheritHandles,
        Int32 dwCreationFlags,
        IntPtr lpEnvironment,
        String lpCurrentDirectory,
        ref STARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo,
        out PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation
    );





    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern UInt32 WaitForSingleObject
    (
        IntPtr hHandle,
        UInt32 dwMilliseconds
    );

    [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern Boolean CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

    #endregion

    #region Functions

    public static int LaunchCommand(string command, string domain, string account, string password)
    {
        int ProcessId = -1;
        PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo = new PROCESS_INFORMATION();
        STARTUPINFO startInfo = new STARTUPINFO();
        Boolean bResult = false;

        UInt32 uiResultWait = WAIT_FAILED;

        var token = ValidateParametersAndGetFirstLoginToken(domain, account, password);

        var duplicateToken = IntPtr.Zero;
        try
        {

            startInfo.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(startInfo);
            //  startInfo.lpDesktop = "winsta0\\default";

            bResult = CreateProcessAsUser(
                token,
                null,
                command,
                IntPtr.Zero,
                IntPtr.Zero,
                false,
                0,
                IntPtr.Zero,
                null,
                ref startInfo,
                out processInfo
            );

            if (!bResult) { throw new Exception("CreateProcessAsUser error #" + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()); }

            // Wait for process to end
            uiResultWait = WaitForSingleObject(processInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);

            ProcessId = processInfo.dwProcessId;

            if (uiResultWait == WAIT_FAILED) { throw new Exception("WaitForSingleObject error #" + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()); }

        }
        finally
        {
            if (token != IntPtr.Zero)
                CloseHandle(token);
            if (duplicateToken != IntPtr.Zero)
                CloseHandle(duplicateToken);
            CloseHandle(processInfo.hProcess);
            CloseHandle(processInfo.hThread);
        }

        return ProcessId;
    }


    private static IntPtr ValidateParametersAndGetFirstLoginToken(string domain, string username, string password)
    {


        if (!RevertToSelf())
        {
            ErrorLogger.LogEvent("RevertToSelf call to remove any prior impersonations failed", System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Error, "");
            throw new Exception("RevertToSelf call to remove any prior impersonations failed");
        }

        IntPtr token;

        var result = LogonUser(username,
                               domain,
                               password,
                               LogonType.LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE,
                               LogonProvider.LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT,
                               out token);
        if (!result)
        {
            var errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            ErrorLogger.LogEvent(string.Format("Could not impersonate the elevated user.  LogonUser: {2}\\{1} returned error code: {0}.", errorCode, username, domain), System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Error, "");
            throw new Exception("Logon for user " + username + " failed.");
        }
        return token;
    }

    #endregion

}
```

and executing it doing the following

```
string commandLine = "Robocopy " + args;

ProcessId = CreateProcess.LaunchCommand(commandLine, ImperDomain, ImperUsername, ImperPassword);
```

I also had to make some changes to the local policy since I want able to copy permissions in robocopy.

Thanks for all the comments and help.

Comment: Are you in Windows 10? I used it and continue to receive Access denied with your code.

Comment: I am not using windows 10. What type of command are you using. And have you tried running that command on the windows 10 machine with that user you are impersonating?

Comment: Your Impersonation class worked perfectly in my Windows Service, thanks!