# C# Windows Service Opening File For User

Tags: c#, service, local

It's my first time creating windows service, and I am trying to open an **Executable File** for currently **Logged In User**, while the service is running as **Local Service,** or **Local System,** but what I am encountering is that **Executable** runs as **SYSTEM** user but doesn't show it to the **User** by that I mean that the process is **Running** under **SYSTEM** user without showing a **Window** for the **Logged In User**.

If my windows service is running as **Local Service**, then it doesn't appear that **Executable File** is able to **RUN**. No signs of life in the Task Manager.

I have tried looking up my problem and tried these solutions:

1. Process.Start("FileName");
2. File.Open("FileName", FileMode.Open); Didn't do anything! (No signs of life in task manager)
3. ProcessStartInfo("FileName") with Verb = "run as"; Didn't change anything (Running as SYSTEM)
4. Tried shell command from Command Prompt: Process.Start("run as (Forgot the whole command line I typed)"); Didn't do anything! (No signs of life in task manager)
5. ProcessStartInfo("FileName") with Username = "User" without Password; Didn't do anything! (No signs of life in task manager)

I do think that solution 4 and 5 didn't work because **Password** is required, but according to **Microsoft Post** about **Local System** it says that **SYSTEM** doesn't need a **Password** to access a **User** (**Impersonation**), but I dont understand what **Impersonation** really is, it seems to do something with **Win API Natives**.

What I think is that the **Executable File Window** is actually shown to the **SYSTEM** when **Executable** is running. Not to the currently logged in **User**.

Now:

1. Is there a **Solution** to my problem without **WinAPI Natives**?
2. If **Natives** are necessary, could you also try to explain it to me? When posting the code? I only understand **Handles** of **WinAPI** that's all I really do understand.
3. Could this be possible on **Local System** running service? As my service is focused to do **System Management**? Instead of **Local Service**.
4. Is it possible to do all of this in **C# Programming Language**?

**PS**: The project I am working on is a **System Management Toolkit** for my company. For future projects.
**PS2**: If you need any more **Information** tell me and I will check this post **Frequently**.
**PS3**: Sorry for my English, if you see any grammar mistakes.

Comment: **PS4**: My Operating System is Windows 10

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38274533/impersonate-user-in-windows-service

Comment: StartInfo and  File.Open() do not start processes, maybe a bit of googling would help you there.

Comment: I did do a lot of googling but I am unable to find the solution to my problem yet, and I do know that StartInfo suppose to be in Process.Start. If I'll find the solution to my problem I will post it as soon as possible.

Comment: Please describe in more detail what you are really trying to achieve. Do you want to start an application? Do you want to open a file with the application mapped to the filetype? It is unclear to me what your goal is.

Comment: Opening would be executing it, like opening up **notepad, regedit, task manager, explorer**. Yes, I want to **start** an application. I think I am getting closer to my **Solution** too, it has something to do with **Task Scheduler API**. Still collecting information.

Comment: Alright so I know what I need to do to achieve this without natives or complex coding. Very simple, as **SYSTEM** User I have privileges to access anything, so what we need to do is create a **Task** in **Task Scheduler**, and tell our **Task** to **Start/Open/Execute** any file we want on specific **User**, it can even be **SYSTEM** User if we want to. Then when we have created our **Task** we need to simply run it **Manually** or let a **Trigger** do that for us. Done, when the task is running then our task will see what we want to **Start/Open/Execute** and it will do that for us.

Comment: On specified **User** in our **Task**. I am not going to explain much but **Task Scheduler API** is the way to do it, if you want things simple. If you are wondering but what if the **User** has a **Password? Then the **Password** will be completely **Ignored**, because the **Task** was created with high enough privileges to well lets just say **Impersonate** our specified **User**. Again I am not going to explain much, just look it up, but that's the way to do it! I am going to write some code and then post the answer with all explanations that are required.

Comment: Quick update: I did everything and it was a complete **success** in just about 30 lines of code without accessing any **internals/natives**. **Very simple**. Answer will be posted shortly! **People that had the same issue will be able to use this solution to solve their problem the simplest way possible!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution code**:

```
using (TaskService taskService = new TaskService())
            {
                TaskDefinition taskDefinition = taskService.NewTask();
                taskDefinition.RegistrationInfo.Description = "Does something";
                taskDefinition.RegistrationInfo.Author = "SYSTEM";

                taskDefinition.Principal.DisplayName = "Testing Display Task Name C#";
                taskDefinition.Principal.RunLevel = TaskRunLevel.Highest;
                taskDefinition.Principal.GroupId = "Administrators";
                taskDefinition.Principal.UserId = "ACCOUNT";
                taskDefinition.Principal.LogonType = TaskLogonType.InteractiveToken;

                taskDefinition.Settings.AllowDemandStart = true;
                taskDefinition.Settings.AllowHardTerminate = true;
                taskDefinition.Settings.DisallowStartIfOnBatteries = false;
                taskDefinition.Settings.DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession = true;
                taskDefinition.Settings.Hidden = false;
                taskDefinition.Settings.RestartCount = 0;
                taskDefinition.Settings.RunOnlyIfIdle = false;
                taskDefinition.Settings.RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable = false;
                taskDefinition.Settings.StartWhenAvailable = true;
                taskDefinition.Settings.StopIfGoingOnBatteries = false;
                taskDefinition.Settings.Volatile = false;
                taskDefinition.Settings.WakeToRun = false;

                taskDefinition.Actions.Add(new ExecAction("notepad.exe"));

                const string taskName = "Testing TASK";
                taskService.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition(taskName, taskDefinition);

                taskService.FindTask("Testing TASK").Run();

            }
```

The solution is **Task Scheduler API**, I don't want to explain much but this is very simple.

To do this what you need is to access **Task Scheduler API** but most of the code is **Unmanaged(c++)** and we don't want that. We want **C# Managed Task Scheduler API**, to do this we need to download this **Nuget Package**: [LINK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TaskScheduler/).

This will give us access to **Task Scheduler API** in **C#** with very good **Managed** and **Documented** code. If you dont know what **Task Scheduler API** is then look it up its very easy to understand.

Then we write our **Task** and we **Run** it, its going to **Start/Open/Execute** specified **Application** on specified **User** with **UAC** without prompt if required. Done its that simple! **NO NATIVES REQUIRED**!

Now for more detailed explanation lets take our example solution code from the top of the answer. At **RegisterInfo.Author** we specify which **User** is creating this **Task**, in this case we write **SYSTEM** because our service is **Local System**. Then at **Principal.GroupID** we write which **Group** our **User** that we want to execute the file is on. In my case the **User** lets say is a **Administrator** that means its going to be in **Administrators** group. Then finally at **Principal.UserId** we write instead of ACCOUNT which user in **Administrators Group** we want to **Start/Open/Execute** the file on lets say **John**. Thats it! if you'll run the code its going to open notepad.exe on that **User**!. I don't want to explain much if someone want's to can improve my answer but this is the way to do it.

**PS**: Keep in mind that you need to have atleast **Administrator Privileges** to create a **Task**. 
**PS2**: For very good **Documentation** about this **C# Managed Task Scheduler API** check this [LINK](https://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples&referringTitle=Home).

Thats all! I might **Improve** this answer later on I dont have much time right now.

Comment: **PS3**: After you create that task and it finished its job its **Recommended** to **REMOVE** it! Unless you are going to use it **Multiple Times**.

Comment: how to remove a task is it by using `dispose()` methode?