# Impersonate User in Windows Service in Windows 10

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I am currently working on Windows service.
The service need to impersonate the user.

I have tried different code but is still cannot impersonate.
It always uses **NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM** as current user.

I have tried codes from below link

[Impersonate user in Windows Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38274533/impersonate-user-in-windows-service)

I am using windows 10.

Comment: Impersonation in a Windows service is a bit tricky using C#.  You can see if this can help you somehow: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsimpersonationcontext?view=netframework-4.8.1&viewFallbackFrom=net-5.0

Comment: For me, this has helped. Thanks @SimmeD